# Spacing using operators

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Why do I get two different outputs from the following lines (in plain TeX)?

```
$f=\mathop{\rm id}_Y\circ f$

$f={\mathop{\rm id}_Y}\circ f$

\bye
```

[image]

In both, an operator is used, but in the first one the `f` is too close to the binary symbol `\circ`; in the second one, by grouping the operator the glyph is well arranged.

How can I get the second output currently in my document without grouping the operators each time?

Comment: In the first example, a math operator is to the left of `\circ`, wheras in the 2nd example, a math atom is to the left of the `\circ`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes so that I should write the line in the second way or even `\mathop {\rm id}_Y{}\circ f`?

Comment: It's not an operator: just use `{\rm id}`.

Comment: @egreg indeed, it is a mapping name so I shall mean it as an operator,  thus the line `\mathop {\rm id}(x)` is correctly spaced

Comment: @Lorenzo No, `\mathop` has a very specific meaning, which is inappropriate in this case. You get exactly the same spacing with `${\rm id}(x)$` and with `$\mathop{\rm id}(x)$`, but the latter behaves badly in other situations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You get different spacing because of the rules of TeX.

With `$f=\mathop{\rm id}_Y\circ f$` we have

> **Ord Rel Op Bin Ord**

Looking at the table at page 170 of the TeXbook, we can add the spacing between the atoms:

> **Ord 3 Rel 3 Op 1 Ord* Ord**

Note that the **Bin** atom is turned into **Ord**, because the combination **Op Bin** is rejected. It's like `$\log-1$`, after all. So the **Bin** is turned into an **Ord** atom. The numbers represent spaces in the form 1=`\thinmuskip`, 2=`\medmuskip` and 3=`\thickmuskip`.

With `$f={\mathop{\rm id}_Y}\circ f$` we get

> **Ord Rel Ord Bin Ord**

because the braces around a subformula make it into an **Ord** atom, so the spacing is

> **Ord 3 Rel 3 Ord 2 Bin 2 Ord**

The symbol for the identity map is *not* an operator, but an ordinary atom and

```
{\rm id}
```

is what you need. Using `\mathord{\rm id}` is more semantic, but completely equivalent.